# Why is my 20.04 System Sounds volume slider non-functional?

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control

In my Sound settings interface, ostensibly I can separately adjust the volume of System Sounds, such as the alert notification sound. But adjusting this slider--even setting it to mute--has no effect. The same problem exists when adjusting it from pavucontrol. How can I diagnose and fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Is the audio going through an HDMI cable to your monitor and being processed from there? I've found that I'm unable to control the volume on my own machine when the output runs through an external display.

Comment: @Matigo It's going through a USB headset. I can adjust the System Volume just fine, but not System Sounds.

Answer (score 0):

When I used Ubuntu 14.04 a long time ago, I had a similar problem when I used the optical (SPDIF) audio output. The volume was fixed at maximum and there was no way to control it via the computer volume program. But at the time, my impression of digital audio outputs was that you would control it from the audio device you use, which in my case was an amplifier with a dial anyway.

I since have used 18.04 and just switched to 20.04 and use pulseaudio myself. I now use a USB DAC for my computer audio and don't seem to have a problem adjusting the system sounds. One USB headset I had had a volume control on the cable which actually controlled the system volume. Are yours only able to be adjusted by your computer volume?

I'm not sure if any of this will help. I just remember having a similar problem myself years ago.